# Django- ListView returning a list of users with a given tag in a tag field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to return a list of users with a particular skill and skills is a TagField (django taggit) in a CustomUser model. I'm struggling to get the queryset right in my ListView (skill_list.html). I want to be able to click on the skill listed on a user's profile (profile.html) and then have that return the skill list page with a list of all users that have that skill.

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    position = models.CharField(max_length =200, null=True, default='', 
    blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, default='', 
    blank=True)
    skills = TaggableManager(help_text="A comma-separated list of tags.")
```

views.py:

```
class SkillView(ListView):
model = CustomUser
template = 'skill_list.html'
queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(skills__name__in= 
    [self.kwargs['skill']])
    return queryset
```

profile.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="profile_container">

            <div class="container skills">
            {% for skill in user.skills.all %}
                <div class="skill_bubble"><p class="skill_bubble"><a href=" 
{% url 'skills' %}">{{ skill.name }}</a></p></div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

skill_list.html:

```
<div class="container">

    {% for user in object_list %}

        <div class="container user_name">
        <p class="profile_name"><a href="{% url 'profile_with_pk' 
pk=user.pk %}">{{ user.first_name }}&nbsp{{ user.last_name }}</a></p>
        <p class="profile_text">{{user.position}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I have the url set up on the profile page to return the 'skill_list.html', however I get an key error on the skill_list page: Exception value "skill."

Comment: You haven't shown your URL pattern. For `self.kwargs['skill']` to work, you need to include the skill in the URL.

Comment: Do you mean include a pk for the customuser model so I can access the skill associated with it? My url is:  path('skills/', views.SkillView.as_view(), name='skills'). I know how to do this for a model instance, but I'm a bit confused now because this is not a model instance but a model field with many entries.

Comment: You want a list of users with the skill, so you need to include the *skill* in the URL, not the user's PK. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to click on the skill listed on a user's profile (profile.html) and then have that return the skill list page

In that case, the URLs need to include the skill in them, e.g. `/skills/python/` or `/skills/sql/`.

You can do this by changing the URL to something like:

```
path('skills/<slug:skill>', views.SkillView.as_view(), name='skills')
```

Now `self.kwargs['skill']` will work in the `SkillView.get_queryset` method.

You now need to include the skill in the URL tag, for example:

```
{% url 'skills' skill %}
```

Finally, since you are only using a single item in your list,

```
queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(skills__name__in=[self.kwargs['skill']])
```

you can remove the `__in` and change the query to:

```
queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(skills__name=self.kwargs['skill'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I'm not getting an error but the list is empty. Do you know if I'm supposed to reference the queryset in the skill_list.html template like so:        {% for user in object_list %} ?

Comment: `{% for user in object_list %}` [should work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts). Try adding some printing/logging to your queryset to make sure that it is returning results

Comment: So I've determined that the problem is not with how I'm calling the queryset in the template. The line: queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(skills__name=self.kwargs['skill']) is not finding the name of the skills properly. Is this how I should reference the skill in the profile.html: <a href="{% url 'skills' skill.slug %}">{{ skill.name }}</a> ?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the skill in the `{% url %}` tag somehow, but I'm not familiar with django taggit so I'm not sure whether the correct usage is `{% url 'skills' skill.name %}` or something slightly different.

Comment: That was it! Thanks sooo much

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be :`request.user` instead of `user` in profile.html

Comment: No, that template works fine when I change the queryset to something else. The problem is with getting the correct queryset. I think the issue is with this line: queryset = CustomUser.objects.filter(skills__name__in= 
    [self.kwargs['skill']])

Answer (score 0):

Then why dont you just use a 'Q' search query. Check it in the docs